# Gas estimation failed when calling the play function

Tags: solidity, remix, testnets

I am trying to deploy this contract on the test network and am able to do so successfully but when i try to call the play function i get gas estimation error and can do nothing further.
I am using remix connected to Ropsten.
To works fine in javascript vm.
Can anyone tell me whats wrong?
ps: i didnt forget to send ether when i called the play function

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

contract test1 {

uint256 count =0;
address payable owner;
address[] public players;

 constructor () public { //constructor
    owner = msg.sender; 

 }


function play() payable public { 
            require (msg.value >= 100000000000000000);
            players[count]=msg.sender;
    count++; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code *shouldn't* work in the JavaScript VM (or anywhere else).

`players` is a dynamically-sized array, initially with size 0. So attempting to write to `players[0]` will fail bounds checking.

You may be used to a language that allows such writes, but in Solidity you have to either explicitly increase the size of the array first (`players.length += 1`) or just use `players.push(msg.sender)` to extend the array and put a value in the newly available spot in the array. You can then get rid of the `count` variable, which is redundant with `players.length`.

Comment: i will try that out, appreciated